# Search a directory for files created between two dates

Tags: vb.net, file, date, search, directory

I am trying to search for all files in a specified folder, which were created between two dates.

The dates are selected from two datetimepickers.

I found this for C#:

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo(your_dir);
var files = directory.GetFiles()
.Where(file => file.LastWriteTime >= DateTimePicker1
&& file.LastWriteTime <= datetimerpicker2);
```

Which I have changed to:

```
Dim Directory = New DirectoryInfo("C:\Test")
Dim path As String
path = (TextBox1.Text)
Dim files = Directory.GetFiles().Where(File.GetLastWriteTime(path) >= DateTimePicker1 And File.GetLastWriteTime <= datetimerpicker2)
```

I am obviously getting some syntax etc wrong.

The results (file path and name) will be posted to Listbox1. I would also like to be able to open the file path by clicking on its Listbox entry but that's something I haven't started to look into.

Any ideas for a solution in VB.NET?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the [`DateTimePicker.Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value(v=vs.110).aspx) property. Also use VB.NET instead of C# syntax:

```
Dim files = From file in directory.EnumerateFiles()
            Where file.LastWriteTime >= DateTimePicker1.Value AndAlso file.LastWriteTime <= Datetimerpicker2.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Tim Schmelter's help, I got the desired result using;

```
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    Dim csvFiles = From csv In Directory.EnumerateFiles(TextBox1.Text, "*.*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                   Where File.GetCreationTime(csv).Date >= DateTimePicker1.Value AndAlso File.GetCreationTime(csv) <= DateTimePicker2.Value

    For Each csvPath In csvFiles
        ListBox1.Items.Add(csvPath)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Even if Tim's answer isn't _**exactly**_ this, you still ought to mark it as accepted since it did infact help you solve 90% of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim path As String = TextBox1.Text
    LoadListBox(path)
End Sub

Private csvFiles As List(Of String)
Private Sub LoadListBox(path As String)
    Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(path)
    di.EnumerateFiles("*.*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    csvFiles = (From csv In di.EnumerateFiles("*.*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                Where csv.CreationTime.Date >= DateTimePicker1.Value.Date AndAlso
                 csv.CreationTime.Date <= DateTimePicker2.Value.Date
                 Select csv.FullName).ToList

    ListBox1.DataSource = csvFiles

End Sub
```